# Matching custom claims with firestore document id

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My data looks roughly like this:

```
/databases/schools/{schoolId}/faculty
                             /students
                             /etc
```

I have a group of people with a customClaim "schoolId" on their accounts. I only want them to be able to access the faculty, students, etc, of the school they belong to. Tried many iterations of this rule, the latest one being

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/schools/{document} {
    match /{doc=**} {
      allow read, write: if user.token.schoolId == document;
    }
  }
}
```

Other iterations include:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/schools/{document} {
    allow read, write: if user.token.schoolId == document;
  }
}
```

and

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/schools {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if user.token.schoolId == document;
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{$document} {
      allow read, write: if resource.id == user.token.schoolId;
    }
  }
}
```

This feels like it should be a fairly simple thing to do but I cannot figure it out (I'm on my 12th iteration)

I think I understand that the last one isn't working because if I try to get /databases/schools/school1/faculty/abc123 then the resource.id actually refers to abc123 and not school1.

An example user looks like this when I decode the token:

```
uid: "gobblygook"
displayName: null
photoURL: null
email: "test-email@yopmail.com"
emailVerified: true
phoneNumber: null
isAnonymous: false
apiKey: "{apikey}"
appName: "[DEFAULT]"
authDomain: "{mydomain}.firebaseapp.com"
lastLoginAt: "1538972960000"
createdAt: "1538868952000"
schoolId: "school1"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

     match schools/{schoolId} {
       allow read: if request.auth.token.schoolId == resource.data.schoolId;
       allow write: if request.auth.token.schoolId == request.resource.data.schoolId;
     }        

  }
}
```

Note that:

1. I guess that with `/databases/schools/{schoolId}/` you mean that the root collection is `schools` and not `databases`.
2. You have to use `request.auth.token.schoolId` in order to retrieve the Custom Claim through the user's ID token, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims
3. The use of `request.resource.data.schoolId;` in the write rule, instead of `resource.data.schoolId;`

Comment: That didn't appear to do it. When I pasted the rule, it complained about bad formatting so I changed line 4 to be match /schools/{schoolId} { but I am still getting permission denied. I am also not seeing any mention of the word resource in the documentation you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up figuring it out this morning, thanks to the Renaud for pointing me in the right direction! Also thanks to this SO answer [Recursive wildcards in Firestore security rules not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47096812/recursive-wildcards-in-firestore-security-rules-not-working-as-expected)

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /schools/{schoolId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.token.schoolId == schoolId
    }

    match /schools/{schoolId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.token.schoolId == schoolId
    }
  }
}
```

Appears to be doing what I want it to do (I can switch == equals to != and my user no longer has access)